# How not close application after driver.quit()

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am using Appium to install an application. After installation the application should work in the background. Another test should use Chrome to check Internet connectivity while the application is working in the background.
The issue is that driver.quit() or even initiating a new instance of a AndroidDriver kills the application and it does not work in the background any more.
Is there a way to test Chrome while the installed application is still working in the background?

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Xiaomi A2 Lite");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPLICATION_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, "false");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, "true");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, "false");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.waze");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.waze.FreeMapAppActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities2.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        capabilities2.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Xiaomi A2 Lite");
        capabilities2.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
        capabilities2.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPLICATION_NAME, "Android");
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver2;

        driver2 = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities2);
        driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver2.get("http://google.com");

        MobileElement googleLogo=(MobileElement) driver2.findElement(MobileBy.id("hplogo"));
        Assert.assertEquals(googleLogo.isDisplayed(), true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to keep application in the background while opening another application by using

```java
Activity activity = new Activity(appPackage, appActivity);
driver.startActivity(activity);
```

However this solution do not work if driver was initiated while app capability is set -for installing apk file

```java
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apkPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with a sample class implementing [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class BackgroundThread implements Callable {

    AppiumDriver driver;
    Duration duration;

    public BackgroundThread(AppiumDriver driver, Duration duration) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() {
        driver.runAppInBackground(duration);
        return "Slept for " + duration.toString();
    }
}
```

When you need to send your application to the background and do something else while it is there - call it with the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Object> result = executorService.submit(new BackgroundThread(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60)));
```

You might also find [DeviceAction](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/DeviceAction) command useful, for instance you can mimic "Home" button click which will send the app to the background and return the context immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried this solution, however, it seems to kill the application before launching chrome. I edited my original question above to include your solution. See that waze application is opened and before chrome launches waze no longer run at the background (GPS is down and no waze entry at android notification window)